Web scraping problem in Python using Jupyter Notebook
I have a task i need to do for an assignment but i can not for the life of me figure it out. The task is as follows:

Write a Python application that can be used to scrape data from the CareerJuction website (at careerjunction.co.za). The application must allow the user to enter a job title to search for, then for each result (on the first result page only) extract the following information:

The job title

The Name of the recruiter

The job salary

The job position

The job location

The date posted


(8 Marks)

The task does state that we need to use careerjunction.co.za but we got permission to use indeed.com, so i have been using that instead.
I have tried many types of code but every time i just get errors, or 403 Forbidden.
The 1st code that i have tried:
def scrape_careerjunction(job_title):
    url = f"https://www.careerjunction.co.za/jobs/results/?keyword={job_title}"
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    }

    # Send HTTP request
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
        jobs = []
     
        # Find all job listings
        job_listings = soup.find_all('div', class_='listing-item')
    
        for job in job_listings:
            job_title = job.find('h2', class_='title').text.strip()
            recruiter = job.find('span', class_='company').text.strip()
            salary = job.find('span', class_='salary').text.strip()
            position = job.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
            location = job.find('span', class_='area').text.strip()
            date_posted = job.find('span', class_='time').text.strip()
        
            job_info = {
                'Job Title': job_title,
                'Recruiter': recruiter,
                'Salary': salary,
                'Position': position,
                'Location': location,
                'Date Posted': date_posted
            }
        
            jobs.append(job_info)
        
        return jobs
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data, status code: {response.status_code}")
        return []

2nd one:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to scrape job data from Indeed
def scrape_jobs(job_title):
    # Replace spaces in job_title with '+'
    job_title = job_title.replace(' ', '+')

    # The base URL of Indeed
    base_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q='

    # Complete URL with the job title
    search_url = f'{base_url}{job_title}'

    # Send a request to the website
    response = requests.get(search_url)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the content with BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
        # Find all job entries - this will depend on the website's structure
        job_entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard') # Replace with  actual class
    
        for job in job_entries:
            # Extract the required information
            job_title = job.find('h2', class_='title').text.strip() # Replace with actual class
            company_name = job.find('span', class_='company').text.strip() # Replace with actual class
            job_location = job.find('span', class_='location').text.strip() # Replace with actual class
            job_summary = job.find('div', class_='summary').text.strip() # Replace with actual class
        
            # Print the extracted information
            print(f'Job Title: {job_title}')
            print(f'Company Name: {company_name}')
            print(f'Location: {job_location}')
            print(f'Summary: {job_summary}')
            print('-----------------------------------')
    else:
        print('Failed to retrieve the webpage')

# Example usage
job_to_search = input('Enter a job title to search for: ')
scrape_jobs(job_to_search)

3rd one:
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_url(position, location):
    """Generate a url from position and location"""
    template = 'https://za.indeed.com/jobs?q={}&l={}'
    url = template.format(position, location)
    return url

url = get_url('senior accountant', 'charlotte nc')

response = requests.get(url)
response

4th one:
    # import module 
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


    # user define function 
    # Scrape the data 
    # and get in string 
def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 

# Get Html code using parse 
def html_code(url): 

    # pass the url 
    # into getdata function 
    htmldata = getdata(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser') 

    # return html code 
    return(soup) 

# filter job data using 
# find_all function 
def job_data(soup): 
    
    # find the Html tag 
    # with find() 
    # and convert into string 
    data_str = "" 
    for item in soup.find_all("a", class_="jobtitle turnstileLink"): 
        data_str = data_str + item.get_text() 
    result_1 = data_str.split("\n") 
    return(result_1) 

# filter company_data using 
# find_all function 


def company_data(soup): 

    # find the Html tag 
    # with find() 
    # and convert into string 
    data_str = "" 
    result = "" 
    for item in soup.find_all("div", class_="sjcl"): 
        data_str = data_str + item.get_text() 
    result_1 = data_str.split("\n") 

    res = [] 
    for i in range(1, len(result_1)): 
        if len(result_1[i]) > 1: 
            res.append(result_1[i]) 
    return(res) 


# driver nodes/main function 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # Data for URL 
    job = "data+science+internship"
    Location = "Noida%2C+Uttar+Pradesh"
    url = "https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q="+job+"&l="+Location 

    # Pass this URL into the soup 
    # which will return 
    # html string 
    soup = html_code(url) 

    # call job and company data 
    # and store into it var 
    job_res = job_data(soup) 
    com_res = company_data(soup) 

    # Traverse the both data 
    temp = 0
    for i in range(1, len(job_res)): 
        j = temp 
        for j in range(temp, 2+temp): 
            print("Company Name and Address : " + com_res[j]) 

        temp = j 
        print("Job : " + job_res[i]) 
        print("-----------------------------") 

With some of these i can enter values but get nothing in return, and yes i did modify the codes via the correct classes, and other just gives me 403 Forbidden
